# Are vertex buffers created on another thread than the DXDevice was created on, slower?

Tags: directx-10

If I create a bunch of vertex buffers (that is, DX10 Buffers set to hold vertices) using multi-threading, will they be slower (to draw as primitives) than ones created on the same thread as the DXDevice?

I ask because the DirectX10 DXDevice is slower when presenting from a different thread than it was created on, and I couldn't find an answer on Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once created they sit on your GPU, so speed will be exactly the same.